# PHP - Will exit() stop a script that has ignore_user_abort(true) set?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a script that starts with: `ignore_user_abort(true)`

It sends emails out. The reason I use `ignore_user_abort(true)` is because I am hitting the page using AJAX, and it is possible that the user may close the browser window before the script is done & I want it to continue anyways.

I am wondering if I add `exit()` to the end of the script will that be enough to end the script from running or do I have to use `flush()` or out put some type of text?

Also, am I correct in my asusmption that if I hit a PHP page using AJAX (via jQuery), and add the `ignore_user_abort(true)` to the start of the script it will act the same as if the user were to access the page directly?

Comment: Why don't you try it out, and tell us how it worked ?

Comment: `exit` and "a closed client [HTTP] stream" are different.

Comment: I don't have direct access to the server, so how can I tell if the script stops running? Just because it is done doing its thing, how do I know PHP has stopped running the script without direct access to the server via terminal?

Comment: @pst How would I go about telling the server that "a closed client [HTTP] stream" once the script is finished?

Comment: @tvirelli `ignore_user_abort(true)` means don't stop execution *if the stream is broken* (e.g. the client/user "closes the page" before the request completes). It has no effect on `exit`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it will. [`ignore_user_abort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php) only affects whether the script stops if the browser terminates the page load; it has no effect on anything else.

Comment: So am I correct in my thinking that a page that starts with `ignore_user_abort(true)` that is loaded by AJAX will continue to run even if the client closes the browser or browses away from the page?